# woocommerce Pass product category parameter value

Tags: woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have to pass product category value from page template to woocommerce plugin to display only given category products for shopping because it has 5 category levels. For it I need possible way

Because I think this will not help me [Woo commerce nested category plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-nested-category-layout/)